# Docker / Python / LibreOffice: [Java framework] Error in function createSettingsDocument (elements.cxx). javaldx failed

Tags: python, docker, libreoffice

I'm currently pretty stuck finding a solution for the following error:

```
LibreOfficeError: [Java framework] Error in function createSettingsDocument (elements.cxx).
javaldx failed!
Warning: failed to read path from javaldx
```

I start libreOffice in headless mode with subprocess.run from a Python / gunicorn application, for converting docx into pdf files:

```
args = ['/usr/lib64/libreoffice/program/soffice', '--headless', '--convert-to', 'pdf', '--outdir', pdfDocFolder, tmpDocName]
process = subprocess.run(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, timeout=timeout)
```

The error message above is what I get when trying to start the conversion.
My application runs in a docker container. The odd thing is that it worked out pretty well previously, when I used the S2I build process of OpenShift to build and deploy the image. Now, after abandoning S2I, building the image locally, and deploying it on OpenShift, I get that error message. I found some discussions of the very same error message in other contexts, stating that the working directory must be made writeable for non-root users and exported as HOME. Unfortunately, that didn't make a difference. I made the working dir writeable for all users. HOME is set to the correct directory. There must be some difference in the S2I build process compared to a local docker build, which makes a difference permission-wise.
That's the two Dockerfiles I use for building the image locally:

Base image:

```
FROM centos/python-36-centos7
EXPOSE 8080
USER root

RUN yum -y --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=base,updates update && \
    yum -y install libreoffice && \
    yum -y install unoconv && \
    yum -y install cairo && \
    yum -y install cups-libs && \
    yum -y install java-1.8.0-openjdk && \
    yum clean all -y && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/yum
    
RUN chown 1001:0 /usr/bin/soffice && \
    chown 1001:0 /usr/share/fonts/local && \
    chown -R 1001:0 /usr/lib64/libreoffice && \
    fix-permissions /usr/lib64/libreoffice -P && \
    rpm-file-permissions
    
USER 1001
```

And that's the Dockerfile built on top of the base image:

```
ARG REGISTRY_PATH=
ARG BRANCH_NAME=

FROM $REGISTRY_PATH:$BRANCH_NAME-latest
USER root

ENV APP_ROOT=/opt/app-root
ENV PATH=${APP_ROOT}/bin:${PATH} HOME=${APP_ROOT}/src
COPY src ${APP_ROOT}/src
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN mkdir -p ${APP_ROOT}/.config/libreoffice/4/user && \
    chmod -R a+rwx ${APP_ROOT}/src && \
    chgrp -R 0 ${APP_ROOT}/src && \
    chmod -R g=u ${APP_ROOT}/src /etc/passwd

EXPOSE 8080

USER 1001
WORKDIR ${APP_ROOT}/src

CMD ["gunicorn", "wsgi", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8080", "--config", "config.py"]
```

Some hints or ideas to try out would really help me, since I completely ran out of options to pursue.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I know this comes too late, but I was experiencing the same issue on a SpringBoot microservice I wrote recently, and for me the solution was to set the HOME env variable to a folder assigned to the group "0", since Openshift runs containers with random users for security reasons, but all of them belonging to the '0' group. Here's my dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.io/eclipse-temurin:17.0.5_8-jre-alpine
RUN apk update &&  apk upgrade --no-cache
RUN apk add libreoffice

RUN chgrp -R 0 /tmp && chmod -R g=u /tmp

ENV HOME /tmp

ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "java ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar /app.jar"]
```

The most important instruction is the

```
RUN chgrp -R 0 /tmp && chmod -R g=u /tmp
```

assigning the right group to the folder which I will set as the HOME path. This kind of directive helped me solve several problems when migrating docker containers to Openshift and it's suggested by redhat itself in the official guide to build images:

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.9/openshift_images/create-images.html

hope this helps! :)